# SQL Select data from previous month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am able using the code below to select data from any number of days in the past but what if I only want the data from the previous month, e.g. from 60 days ago to 30 days ago.

I thought I might be able to use `INTERVAL 60 - 30`, but I am not sure that is working...

```
SELECT
    product,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    Date(OrderDate) <= CURDATE() AND 
    Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)

GROUP BY
    product
ORDER BY CountOf DESC
```

Thoughts?

Comment: That query selects 30 days in the past starting today. Using DATE_SUB in the start and the end date of the interval, you can select dates between 60-30 days in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment:

```
Date(OrderDate) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
Date(OrderDate) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

Note:  if `OrderDate` is already a date, then don't use the `DATE()` function.  It can prevent the use of indexes.

Even if `OrderDate` has a time component, you probably still don't need the `DATE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the MySQL functions `MONTH()` and `NOW()`? You can use these in your where clause:

```
MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1
```

Of course, this needs to be fine tuned for example for years (to get December if it is January).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function supports the use of `MONTH` as an interval, so you should be able to use that if you wanted the data for the previous month from the current date :

```
Date(OrderDate) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
SELECT
    product,
    COUNT(OrderNumber) AS CountOf
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking' AND
    YEAR(orderdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND MONTH(orderdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)   
GROUP BY
    product
ORDER BY CountOf DESC
```